# Salesforce Bulk API 2.0 in SSIS Script Task

Tags: ssis, salesforce, script-task

Have anyone tried using Salesforce BULK API 2.0 in SSIS Script task. I was able to create the job and generate the CSV from the SQL query but when I am trying to use the HTTP PUT method for adding the data to the job it is not working. Following the link to create the steps on how to create job and then add data to the job.
[https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/v/modules/api_basics/api_basics_bulk#:~:text=Bulk%20API%20is%20based%20on,the%20request%20in%20the%20background](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/v/modules/api_basics/api_basics_bulk#:%7E:text=Bulk%20API%20is%20based%20on,the%20request%20in%20the%20background).

```
//********************CREATE JOB*****************************
            HttpClient createClientCreateJob = new HttpClient();

            String requestCreateJobMessage = "{\"object\" : \"Account\"," +
                                    "\"contentType\" : \"CSV\"," +
                                    "\"operation\" : \"insert\"," +
                                    "\"lineEnding\": \"CRLF\"} ";
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(requestCreateJobMessage);
            HttpContent contentCreateJob = new StringContent(requestCreateJobMessage, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            string uriCreateJob = sfServiceUrl + "/services/data/v50.0/jobs/ingest";
            HttpRequestMessage requestCreateJob = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uriCreateJob);
            requestCreateJob.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + sfOauthToken);
            requestCreateJob.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            requestCreateJob.Content = contentCreateJob;
            HttpResponseMessage responseCreateJob = await createClientCreateJob.SendAsync(requestCreateJob);
            var resultCreateJob = await responseCreateJob.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(resultCreateJob, "resultCreateJob");

            String batchid = resultCreateJob.Substring(7, 18);
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("batch job created successfully - " + batchid);
```

Comment: What specific error or problem behavior are you seeing?

Comment: create job works without any issue. when I am trying to code for put request the csv file is not getting uploaded to the job